# In Snowflake, can you create a circle polygon from a given centre point and radius?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table containing geometrics points (called [Polygon_Centre]) and distances (called [Desired_Radius]). Anybody know which Snowflake function I could use to create polygon circles from this?

I'm trying to achieve a similar result to the [Trade Area](https://help.alteryx.com/current/designer/trade-area-tool) tool in Alteryx if anybody is familiar with that.

I was hoping for something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
ST_MAKEPOLYGON('Circle', [Polygon_Centre], [Desired_Radius])
```

Does anybody know how to create a circle polygon from a given centre point and radius in Snowflake?

Comment: Right now the only input to Snowflake's ST_MAKEPOLYGON function is a LineString with the first and last point the same so it forms forms a loop. To approximate a circle, you could use an octagon or other polygon with more sides. If you're using a circle to geofense, depending on use case you may be able to just use a point and the HAVERSINE function?

Comment: How are you planning to use the circle? Knowing the end goal can help us find an alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody. I've found and used the following solution:

1. Calculate 120 points around the circle mathematically
2. Turn this into an ordered list with ST_COLLECT() (the order is critical and the start and end must match)
3. Use ST_MAKELINE() to turn these points into a line
4. Create the circle with ST_MAKEPOLYGON().

Comment: Cool! Can you share the code to calculate the 120 points? Btw, is it `ST_MAKEPOLYGON()` instead of `ST_CREATEPOLYGON()`?

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the post above to say MAKEPOLYGON(), that was indeed a typo.

My script to achieve this circle is available as a Gist on GitHub:
https://gist.github.com/ChrisHastieIW/fa89ce76582754ebb41c37ede1ae7e92